# Advanced indexing is returning an array with the wrong shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been using [this reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to understand advanced indexing. One specific example is as follows;

***Example***
Suppose x.shape is (10,20,30) and ind is a (2,3,4)-shaped indexing intp array, then result = x[...,ind,:] has shape (10,2,3,4,30) because the (20,)-shaped subspace has been replaced with a (2,3,4)-shaped broadcasted indexing subspace. If we let i, j, k loop over the (2,3,4)-shaped subspace then result[...,i,j,k,:] = x[...,ind[i,j,k],:]. This example produces the same result as x.take(ind, axis=-2).

I've been trying to understand this for a while and to help me I'm got a little script that produces some arrays. I have;

```
Indexing arrays
i => 12 x 25
j => 12 x 25
k => 12 x 1

Input array
x => 2 x 3 x 4 x 4

Output Array
Cols => 2 x 12 x 25
```

The code I use to make Cols is as follows;

```
cols = x[:, k, i, j]
```

From my understanding of the example cols should actually have shape (2 x 12 x 1 x 12 x 25 x 12 x 25). I've come to this as follows;

It's original dimensions are 2 x 3 x 4 x 4

The 2 is unchanged but all other dimensions are altered

The 3 is replaced with k, a 12 x 1 array

The first 4 is replaced by i, a 12 x 25 array

The second 4 is replaced by j, also a 12 x 25 array

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something here, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Also from that docs section: `Advanced indexes always are broadcast and iterated as one:`  In contrast you are applying them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
i=np.random.randint(0,4,(12,25))
j=np.random.randint(0,4,(12,25))
k=np.random.randint(0,3,(12,1))
x=np.random.randint(1,11,(2,3,4,4))

x1 = x[:,k,:,:][:,:,:,i,:][:,:,:,:,:,j]
x1.shape

(2, 12, 1, 12, 25, 12, 25)
```

Why doesn't the original method work that way?  I think it is probably that advanced indexing is greedy in determining whether you're indexing by multiple dimensions simultaneously.  For instance, your original shape:

```
x.shape
(2,3,4,4)
```

Could be interpreted many ways.  What you want is that each axis is independent, but it is just as valid to interpret it as 6 `(4,4)` matrices or 2 `(3,4,4)` tensors.  So when indexing by `[...,i,j]` you can interpret the `i` to be over the third axis and the `j` over the fourth, or that `i,j` is over the last two axes.  Numpy guesses that you mean the second:

```
x[...,i,j].shape
(2,3,12,25)
```

You can also interpret `x` as 8 `(3,4)` matrices, which is what happens when you do:

```
x[:,k,i,:].shape
(2,12,25,4)
```

Notice that is has also broadcasted your `(12,1)` `k` array to `(12,25)` in order to match `i` for indexing.  You can confirm that broadcasting is happening by using `.squeeze()` on `k`:

```
x[:,k.squeeze(),i,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,) (12,25)
```

If you interpret `x` as 2 `(3,4,4)` tensors, numpy does both.  It broadcasts `k` to `(12,25)` and then indexes the last three dimensions against a set of three `(12,25)` indexing arrays, reducing all three as a unit.

You can override this behavior somewhat using `np.ix_`, but all the arguments of `np.ix_` have to be 1d, so you're out of luck there without flattening and reshaping, which sort of defeats the purpose here, but also works:

```
x2 = x[np.ix_(np.arange(x.shape[0]), k.flat, i.flat, j.flat)].reshape((x.shape[0], ) + k.shape + i.shape + j.shape)

x2.shape
(2, 12, 1, 12, 25, 12, 25)

np.all(x1 == x2)
True
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'm really trying to wrap my head around how numpy creates the Cols array, but I just can't hold that many dimensions in my head!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorta not human that way.  Try to see it this way: if `a.shape=(5,5)`, then `a[np.arange(5),np.arange(5)]` isn't the same as `a`, it's the diagonal of `a`, or `[a[1,1], a[2,2], a[3,3], a[4,4], a[5,5]]`.  In other words, `a[np.arange(5),np.arange(5)].shape == arange(5).shape`.

Comment: All three index arrays broadcast to (12,25).   Broadcasting is central to understanding how multiple index arrays act.  Indexing with a (n,) and (n,) produces a (n,) output; indexing with (n,1) and (m) produces a (n,m) output.  Slicing adds a dimension, though there's a gotcha if the slice is in the middle of the indexing tuple.